# Android Gridview - Linear layout_height being ignored

Tags: android, android-layout

According to the accepted answer to this question [GridView row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375962/gridview-row-height), if you...

> "Set your LinearLayouts to be some specific height, and the rows will all be that height."

This does not appear to work in my case. I have a layout file for each row as so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/theimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#ffff0000" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/thename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="?icontext" 
        android:background="#ff00ff00"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And these are contained within a Gridview defined as so:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/gridview" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:background="@color/background" 
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp" />
```

This ignores the 'android:layout_height="200dp"' and instead sets the row height to the cell's content.

What's worse is that when my TextView wraps onto a second line, that second line is obscured by the next row of cells.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you should check this question and it's answer: [Layout problem with button margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315529/layout-problem-with-button-margin)

Comment: Ahh, yes, that makes sense. Maybe you should post this as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is solved in the following question: [Layout problem with button margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315529/layout-problem-with-button-margin)

`android:layout_*` attributes are `LayoutParams` and belong to the parent view. So they will be ignored if you don't specify any parent.

Comment: Thank you! I had a fragment that contained just a TextView, but that view's height was being ignored. Putting a FrameLayout around the view in the fragment fixed that issue.