# Cardslib Card size overflow

Tags: android, gridview, cardslib

I am using Cardslib and marked in the red rectangle, some cards in the grid overflow and joins the next card below. How can i prevent this?

[image: cardslib]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the blog post that explains and solves overlap problem: www.ottodroid.net/?p=330

Answer (score 1):

I have to check this case to find a real solution.

I am pretty sure that it depends by the different height of the title in `CardHeader`.

A possible and quick workaround is to use a fixed height in the header.

Comment: i used a fixed height as following: <style name="card.header_outer_layout">
        <item name="android:layout_height">230dp</item>
    </style> The problem is not resolved. The problem is that some cards overflow but some not. Both cards are similar style and content.

Comment: Is this explain the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545915/gridview-rows-overlapping-how-to-make-row-height-fit-the-tallest-item/7568226#7568226. Fixed height for the CardView may solve the problem, but this looks bad.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. You should choose to fix the header with only 1 line and a smaller text size.