# Dynamically set all item height in GridLayout based on item which has biggest height value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I have created menus with GridLayout. It currently looks like this:

[image]

It looks ugly because item which has biggest height value is different from other item's height.
What I want is to adjust all item's height based on item which has the biggest height value, so all items is in same height. How I can achieve this?

Here is my layout code

```java
 <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:columnCount="2">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/btn_info1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/btn_info2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/btn_info3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/btn_info4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="ITEM WITH MAX HEIGHT"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) then [Barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier) does exactly what you are looking for , i have tried it and it works.

> A Barrier references multiple widgets as input, and creates a virtual guideline based on the most extreme widget on the specified side. For example, a left barrier will align to the left of all the referenced views.

Here is a good tutorial [link](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this,
[GridView rows overlapping: how to make row height fit the tallest item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545915/gridview-rows-overlapping-how-to-make-row-height-fit-the-tallest-item/7568226#7568226)
Also you can set gravity = center  in grid layout to align all items to middle.  if any item height expected goes beyond some limit place it inside scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is your layout where your issue was resolved.
Just copy past this line in your layout file.

```
 <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:columnCount="2">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/btn_info1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minLines="2"        android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/btn_info2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minLines="2"      android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/btn_info3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minLines="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/btn_info4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="ITEM WITH MAX HEIGHT"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>
```