# How to set row height of GridView fit to Screen in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to stretch the row of a GridView to match the height of the screen in Android.
How do I do this?

Comment: does that mean you have only one row in your grid view.Give your layout , that can help to give right answers. This can be achieved either by keeping the height as fill parent .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375962/gridview-row-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are in control over your row heights, by virtue of what you put in
>   them. Since your cells appear to have more than one widget, they are
>   presumably wrapped in a LinearLayout or something. Set your
>   LinearLayouts to be some specific height, and the rows will all be
>   that height.
>
> Personally, I think you should be resizing your images if you are
>   going to have text above and below each image on a per-cell basis.

With the Reference [commonsware link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375962/gridview-row-height/2379461#2379461)

Comment: did u copy/paste Commonsware answer? :))) http://stackoverflow.com/a/2379461/304270 funny..no credits.. :S

Comment: @Ewoks offcourse yes when i post question no one can give answer...after search on net got solution from commonsware's anwer.Also check my answer

Comment: now when u edited for adding reference links seems to be much nicer answer ;)